# Android UI tester monkey - no activities found to run

Tags: android, android-monkey

I am trying to get the android ui monkey running for the first time and am having some problems.

I have run `adb shell monkey -v 100` which works fine, but obviously only on the system UI not on my own application.

I then try

`adb shell monkey -p com.rbennett485.dawnoftheveg -v 100`

and get the output

```
:Monkey: seed=1406692871132 count=100
:AllowPackage: com.rbennett485.dawnoftheveg
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

The relevant section of my manifest is

```
<activity
            android:name="com.rbennett485.dawnoftheveg.DawnOfTheVeg"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Any ideas? I know a lot has been asked about this error before, but it mostly seems to be from not using the full package name - am I using the correct package name here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the package my main activity was in had a different name to the package that was defined in my manifest. By using the manifest package name instead it worked fine